# Read selected data from multiple files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 200 .txt files and need to extract one row data from each file and create a different dataframe.

For example (abc1.txt,abc2.txt, .etc) set of files and i need to extract 5th row data from each file and create a dataframe. When reading files, columns need to be separated by '/t' sign.

like this

```
data = pd.read_csv('abc1.txt', sep="\t", header=None)
```

I can not figure out how to do all this with a loop. Can you help?

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? Can you, please, share a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the type of issues you ran into?

Comment: I did this 

import glob
filenames = glob.glob('/*.TXT')
data = []
for i in filenames:
    data = pd.read_csv('i', sep="\t", header=None)
    data.columns = ['a','b','c'] want to know how to select a row data from all the files and create a dataframe from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('path/to/dir')
files = path.glob('*.txt')

to_concat = []
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t", header=None, nrows=5).loc[4:4]
    to_concat.append(df)

result = pd.concat(to_concat)
```

I have used `nrows` to read only first 5 rows and then `.loc[4:4]` to get dataframe rather than series (when you use `.loc[4]`.

Comment: i get something like this || ab    1.383260e+12
cd    3.900000e+01
ab    1.384038e+12
cd    3.900000e+01||      ab and cd should be column names. do you know how to get that as a dataframe ?

Comment: Can you specify what do you mean? Is this one row you showed?

Comment: i have solved that problem but there is new issue.I have modified the lines in for loop as data1 = pd.read_csv(i, sep="\t", header=None)
    data1.columns = ['number','ab','cd','as','sd','dfg','btr','rfrfr']
    dataset1 = pd.DataFrame(data1.loc[data1.number==1,['number','ab','cd']])
    toconcat.append(dataset1)
    
result = pd.concat(toconcat)
result    this shows the dataframe is 700 by 3 but only shows the data from the last file

Comment: You need to share whole code if you want help. Is `toconcat.append(dataset1)` in for loop?

Comment: Check this i have publish it as a problem again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61650990/concatenation-data-in-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment109052198_61650990

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
directory = 'C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\datafiles\\'
aggregate = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        data = pd.read_csv(directory+filename, sep="\t", header=None)
        row5 = pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[4]).transpose()
        aggregate = aggregate.append(row5)
```

Comment: I'm getting a error for this line "for filename in os.listdir('C:\Users\PC\Desktop\datafiles'):"  like this (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape do you know why? sorry im new to pyhton

Comment: I have added the code with your directory. Note that for \ you need to put in a string \\ (double slash)