# Concatenation data in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Hi the following code only gives me the data from the last file.There is a issue with the concat or the for loop. I am reading data from 2 files. each should contain nearly 350 rows 3 columns that agree the condition in the for loop. So at the end data frame should give nearly 700 by 3 data frame. but it only shows data from the last file.

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\datafiles')
filenames = path.glob('*.txt')
toconcat = []
for i in filenames:
    data1 = pd.read_csv(i, sep="\t", header=None)
    data1.columns = ['number','ab','cd','as','sd','dfg']
    dataset1 = pd.DataFrame(data1.loc[data1.number==1,['number','ab','cd']])
    toconcat.append(dataset1)

result = pd.concat(toconcat)
result
```

But when i used the result.shape it shows 700 by 3 
what is the issue here?

Comment: add sample dataframe and expected output

Comment: When you print your toconcat list, do you see both your dataframes?

Comment: no only data from the last file that reads by the loop

Comment: Check if your for loop iterates over all files, other idea is that only one file meets your condition `data1.number==1`.

Comment: Nope it reads both files. I checked it with using a count. And both files contain data that meets data1.number==1 condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created even a "wider" example, passing also *keys* parameter
(the "origin marker").

Source file *Input_1.txt*:

```
1   ab1 cd1 as1 sd1 dfg1
1   ab2 cd2 as2 sd2 dfg2
1   ab3 cd3 as3 sd3 dfg3
2   ab4 cd4 as4 sd4 dfg4
```

Source file *Input_2.txt*:

```
1   ab5 cd5 as5 sd5 dfg5
1   ab6 cd6 as6 sd6 dfg6
1   ab7 cd7 as7 sd7 dfg7
2   ab8 cd8 as8 sd8 dfg8
```

(both the above files are Tab-separated).

And the code:

```
toconcat = []
keys = []
path = Path(r'C:\Users\...')  # Replace dots with your path
filenames = path.glob('*.txt')
for i in filenames:
    data1 = pd.read_csv(i, sep='\t', names=['number', 'ab', 'cd', 'as', 'sd', 'dfg'])
    dataset1 = data1.loc[data1.number==1, ['number', 'ab', 'cd']]
    toconcat.append(dataset1)
    keys.append(i.stem)
result = pd.concat(toconcat, keys=keys)
print(result)
```

Note that column names can be passed as early as in *read_csv* (as I did).

The result, for my input files, is:

```
           number   ab   cd
Input_1 0       1  ab1  cd1
        1       1  ab2  cd2
        2       1  ab3  cd3
Input_2 0       1  ab5  cd5
        1       1  ab6  cd6
        2       1  ab7  cd7
```

So your code looks OK. My code is different in only this detail that the
result contains MultiIndex, with the top level showing the origin of
each row, thus easing tracing of what has been going on.

Try just my code and my input files, the result should be just like mine.

Then replace one of my files with yours (and run the code).
Finally replace also the second my file with your second file and run
the code again.

Finally delete *keys* parameter, to have an ordinary index in the result.

Probably the source of your error is somewhere else.

By the way: You don't need *import glob*, as you use *glob* from *path* only.